# Accessing stack frame on x86-64 architecture on Linux

Tags: linux, assembly, stack, x86-64

I am trying to access the different stack frames on a Linux system with x86-64 architecture. I am able to access the Register Base Pointer (rbp) of all the frames. Now I want to access the arguments to each function call. I checked this [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/06/stack-frame-layout-on-x86-64/) which says that the first 6 arguments are being passed through registers. However, as far as I understand, I can get only the arguments of the top-most function call by reading the registers. But what about the arguments sent to the other functions (that is, the stack-frames lying below the current frame)? Presumably, they must be stored at some position in the stack itself, but I could not get the location. Can anybody help explain this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: They are not necessarily stored on the stack, so in general you have no way to access them. Also note that using `rbp` as stack frame pointer is optional too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code:

```
int f1(int a1, int a2, int a3) {
  return f2(2 * a1, 2 * a2, 2 * a3);
}

int f2(int a1, int a2, int a3) {
  return a1 + a2 + a3;
}
```

Now say we call f1(): we put its arguments into RDI, RSI, and RDX as per the calling convention.  It then multiplies each of these registers by 2 and calls f2().  Those registers are defined as caller-saved, yet there is no need to save them, since f1() will not use them again.  Therefore, once we are in f2() we cannot reasonably expect to have any way to get the original arguments passed to f1().  They are simply not in existence, and cannot be recovered because there is no way to "undo" even a simple operation like multiply-by-2 (because it might have overflowed).

Comment: But what if those arguments were needed again? In that case, a1, a2 and a3 (of f1) had to be saved somewhere. But where?

Comment: They could be saved in other registers.  :)  But you don't know which.

Comment: Thanks -- but in that case, how is it possible for gdb to do backtrace?

Comment: `gdb` can only backtrace if you compile without optimization and with debug info. Otherwise even `gdb` will just tell you something like this: `main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=<optimized out>)`.

Comment: Write a program which contains `f1` and `f2` as above, and a `void main` which only calls `f1(1,2,3)`. Don't include `stdio` or `printf` or anything else. Now compile it disassemble main and the two `f` functions. Watch how values are stored on the stack and moved around registers as calculations are performed. By the time you're in `f2` you have no way of telling what `f1` was called with, because the register contents have been overwritten.

Comment: The data you're looking for might have been put in other registers, or on the stack, it depends on what the compiler did. Like John said, the compiler has probably decided that these values aren't needed anymore so has overwritten them. If they were still needed (say `f1` calculated `f2` as above, and then did another calculation with the three `a` ints, then returned that) then when you're in `f2` the data containing `f1`'s arguments is either in registers or on the stack.

Comment: @suprjami: pretty much, that's how I confirmed some of the things I wrote above.  I didn't need to disassemble though--I just compiled to assembly and stopped there (e.g. `g++ -S`).  By the way, note that you must use `int main` instead of `void main` - it is not 1988 anymore.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck Hehe yeah I know, C99 defines `int main`, I just wanted to keep this as simple as possible cos assembly is still pretty hard for me :)